# Byzantine Generals: number of faulty processes

Tags: communication, distributed-system, multiple-processes

I was reading Lamport's paper about the Byzantine Generals Problem and I would like to ask the following question: in order to the algorithm work, do I always need to know the number of faulty processes ?? For instance, if I have a network where there is no way of knowing how many processes may generate wrong messages, can't I use Lamport's solution (oral messages or signed messages) ??

Thanks !!

Comment: I think Byzantine Generals Problem is between any 2 processes.

Answer (score 0):

For a real-world implementation, choosing a number M of traitors means how strong your distributed system is. So if you have zero or K < M traitors, your system is protected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the exact number of Byzantine faulty processes in prior before starting the network. All you need to know is the number of processes in total(**n**), which it means that it can tolerate up to **f = (n - 1) / 3** number of Byzantine faulty processes. So you need to specify the total number of processes in the system first, and then you can figure out the number of allowable Byzantine faulty processes by simply calculating following expression: **f = (n - 1) / 3**